# How to enable conditional formatting so that a cell becomes red whenever today's date becomes previous cell's date + work days?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

Cell A1 (till A10) contains random date. I want B2 (till B10) to become red  on the 3rd work day after A1. Also, if B is empty or NA then dont color B.

For example: if A1 = 18Oct, then B1 should become red on 23Oct. If A2 = 21Oct, then B2 should become red on 24Oct.

What code should I put in conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Demo]

Highlight the relevant range in Column B, which is `B1:B4` in the above example, enter the following formula as the formatting rule for conditional formatting:

```
=NETWORKDAYS($A1,$B1)=4
```

Comment: If I want to add another condition to this formula that: If B is empty or NA, then dont color B. How to do that?

Comment: @Gef you could set the default colour of B to  *none*, then add another rule to show a different colour if the difference is not 4 by changing the equal sign to `<>` in my answer.

Comment: @Gef if the empty or NA is returned by formula, you will need to set up a new rule to set the colour to *none* using a formula such as `=LEN($B1)=0`.